# vscodevim: After being idle for a period of time, <esc> to return to 'normal' mode or clear text in command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

vscodevim vim extension in Visual Studio Code.

Sometimes, I forget to hit 'escape' to return to 'normal' mode.  Or, I'll have a partially written command in the text command line that I never actually hit enter to execute.

Is there a way to have vscodevim automatically hit 'escape' after being idle for a period of time?  How?

I see there is some 'timeout' method.  But, I think that is for something else ... ?

Thanks!